Ausstritsgemeinde - Opposition of Rabbi Hirsch to the "Geminderabbiner"
Rabbi Samson Raphael Hirsch was vehemently opposed to the rabbis who didn't follow him when he passed the Ausstritsgesetz (Secession Bill) which allowed Orthodox Jews to separate from the general Jewish Congregation. The latter was a Congregation with a mix of Reform and Orthodox Jews.
(See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samson_Raphael_Hirsch and also Moreinu Jacob Rosenheim's autobiography "Erinnerungen")
I am looking for halachic discussion on the topic, especially by the rabbis of the era.

I forget which East European rabbi wrote to both R' Hirsch and R' Bamburger (who advocated for staying with the community), essentially -- "you each have your points and know your own communities better, nothing else for me to say."

It wouldn't be that different than the logic of the American Orthodox groups who joined the SCA. I once asked for the rationale here. The question was closed before anyone gave one

@Schmerel your SCA question is still open. Some voted to leave it open and some voted to close it, but right now it's still open.
